# Adding user checks to Python turtle tic-tac-toe game

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

```
import turtle
#1)draw board
sc= turtle.Screen()
sc.setup(300,300)
import turtle
sc= turtle.Screen()
sc.setup(300,300)

turtle.speed(0)
turtle.pensize(10)
turtle.bgcolor("black")
turtle.pencolor("white")
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-150,50)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(300)
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-150,-50)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(300)
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-50,150)
turtle.setheading(-90)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(300)
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(50,150)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(300)
turtle.penup()



#2) X's and O's

turtle.pencolor("yellow")
def kreuz(x,y):
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(x+30,y-45)
turtle.setheading(-45)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(x+60,y-40)
turtle.setheading(-130)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(50)
turtle.penup()
def kreis(x,y):
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(x+50,y-80)
turtle.setheading(0)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.circle(20)
turtle.penup()



AlleTeile=["","","","","","","","",""]
nächsterZug="X"

def zeichneTeile (AlleTeile):
x = -150
y = 150
for einTeil in AlleTeile:
    if einTeil=="X":
        kreuz(x,y)
    elif einTeil=="O":
        kreis(x,y)
    else:
        print("leeres feld")
    x=x+100
    if x > 50:
        x=-150
        y=y-100



zeichneTeile(AlleTeile)

def geklickt(x,y):
global nächsterZug,AlleTeile
senkrecht= (x+150) // 100
waagrecht= (-y+150)// 100
Bereich= senkrecht+waagrecht*3
Bereich=int(Bereich)
print("Du klicktest auf Bereich-Nummer", Bereich)
AlleTeile[Bereich]=nächsterZug
if nächsterZug =="X":
    nächsterZug="O"
else:
    nächsterZug="X"
zeichneTeile(AlleTeile)

turtle.onscreenclick(geklickt)
turtle.mainloop()
```

I want to create this tic-tac-toe game using turtle in Python but I am stuck. The problem is that I keep drawing noughts and crosses on the game board after all 9 fields are full with noughts and crosses. How can I code this so that after 9 turns (9 fields) it is no longer possible to keep on drawing?

Comment: It would be helpful to translate the code to English

Comment: I don't see you checking if the array is empty at the point you're trying to mark. You should have some sort of logic that checks that the space is truly empty before allowing the user to place an X or O there: `if AlleTeile[i] != "": print("Teil voll")`

Answer (score 0):

Since unused squares consist of an empty string in `AlleTeile`, this is trivial to fix since empty strings are `False` in a boolean context.  At the top of `geklickt()`, after the `global` statement:

```
if all(AlleTeile):
    print("All taken!")
    return
```

We can reuse the same trick later in that function to prevent overwritting of existing squares.  After the `Bereich` calculation, we can do something like:

```
print("Du klicktest auf Bereich-Nummer", Bereich, end="")
if AlleTeile[Bereich]:
    print(" -- already taken!")
    return
else:
    print()
```

Here's my complete rework with the above changes, some turtle idoms, code cleanup and English translation courtesy of Google (and common sense):

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

# X's and O's

def cross(x, y):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x + 30, y - 35)
    turtle.setheading(-45)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x + 60, y - 30)
    turtle.setheading(-130)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.forward(50)
    turtle.penup()

def nought(x, y):
    turtle.penup()
    turtle.goto(x + 50, y - 70)
    turtle.setheading(0)
    turtle.pendown()
    turtle.circle(20)
    turtle.penup()

# Playing the game

def drawSquares():
    screen.tracer(False)  # because this routine is a graphics bottleneck

    x, y = -150, 150

    for square in AllSquares:
        if square == "X":
            cross(x, y)
        elif square == "O":
            nought(x, y)

        x += 100

        if x > 50:
            x = -150
            y -= 100

    screen.tracer(True)

def clicked(x, y):
    global turn

    if all(AllSquares):
        print("All taken!")
        return

    vertical = (x + 150) // 100
    horizontal = (150 - y) // 100

    Area = int(vertical + horizontal * 3)
    print("You clicked area number", Area, end="")
    if AllSquares[Area]:
        print(" -- already taken!")
        return
    else:
        print()

    AllSquares[Area] = turn

    if turn == "X":
        turn = "O"
    else:
        turn = "X"

    drawSquares()

# Draw the board

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(330, 330)
screen.bgcolor("black")

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.pensize(10)
turtle.color("white")
turtle.speed('fastest')

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-150, 50)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(300)
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-150, -50)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(300)

turtle.setheading(-90)

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-50, 150)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(300)
turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(50, 150)
turtle.pendown()
turtle.forward(300)
turtle.penup()

# Start the game

turtle.color("yellow")

AllSquares = ["", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]

turn = "X"

drawSquares()

screen.onscreenclick(clicked)

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hey cdlane! thank u so much for your help. i am sorry for my bad work but i am a real beginner and i am still learning hard :( now i am trying to figure out how to get a game logic inside the game / like the real difficult part where you need to write which combinations 3 crosses diagonal and so on get u a win and a lose / i am not asking you again to do all my work,this is clearly my part , but could just anyone tell me how to continue now / yet again thank you so much for all your help and your friendliness / hope to hear u again thanks, hans

Comment: @HansSarpei, you should try adding the game scoring logic to your code  and, if you run into trouble, post a new question to SO with the code you've come up with that needs help.